# CSS: How to resize the right side element only?

Tags: html, css

[image: Margin and resizing]

I'd like to display price and description this way. And when the window width is resized, I want only middle part (inside blue rectangle) to be resized.

The red rectangle's width should not change for any window dimension.

I tried to use `<table>` tag, but it makes the first part to be wrapped.

[image: $ sign wrapping]

Here is HTML snippet for this:

```
<table class="notfootable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="usd">$</span><span class="monthly-cost">744.58</span></td>
        <td>
          <h4>Monthly Cost</h4>
          <p class="nomargin">This includes your Account's Subscription Plan as well as any Add-ons for your Account.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that `<span class="usd">` has the following CSS attributes.

```
.usd {   
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #1587AC;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}
```

I added `display: inline-block` to add `margin-top`.

Comment: please add a working example (https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Yes but this can't help us, add other css classes please...

Comment: Please include all code necessary to reproduce the problem as a [mcve] in the question itself. Since you're just using HTML and CSS, you can use the Stack Snippets feature (button looks like `<>` in a page).

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't want this to be formed inside of a `table` tag. It's not tubular data that inside of it. It's content.

Secondly, `flexbox` can come in handy to address this problem that you're having. It's easy to use and has many options to align your content on the x-axis and the y-axis within a `div`.

> The **CSS3 Flexible Box**, or **flexbox**, is a layout mode providing for the
>   arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave
>   predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen
>   sizes and different display devices.

You can read more about `flexbox` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

With that in mind, I made a little sample to recreate what you want to achieve.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.info {
  display: flex;
}
.price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.cta {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .info {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .cta {
    display: block;
    justify-content: initial;
    width: 20%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="price">
      <span class="usd">$</span><span class="monthly-cost">744.58</span>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <h4>Monthly Cost</h4>
      <p>This includes your Account's Subscription Plan as well as any Add-ons for your Account.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
    <button>Billing details</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe to accomplish this you can use `position: absolute` on a `<div>` surrounding the blue rectangle and use  `position:relative` on the parent container surrounding that element. On all other elements inside that container use `position: relative`.

Here is a somewhat similar question to yours:
[DIV absolute positioning - maintain position after browser window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563285/div-absolute-positioning-maintain-position-after-browser-window-resize)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the two span of "usd" and "monthly-cost" within a div that has display display attributes of "inline-block" and a fixed width that is wide enough to accommodate the widest cost amount displays. This should keep those two spans inline as the display width is decreased.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of flex layouts as below:
HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="usd">$</span><span class="monthly-cost">744.58</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-top">
      <h4>Monthly Cost</h4>
      <p class="nomargin">This includes your Account's Subscription Plan as well as any Add-ons for your Account.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bottom">
      <button>billing details</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  align-self: center;
  padding-right: 55px;
}

.right {
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

More on flex layouts:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/